# Get Cosmodb container throughput with powershell Get-AzCosmosDBSqlContainerthroughput

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell

It doesn't give the correct Provisioned throughput value which is of 500 but shows as "0"

```powershell
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-AzCosmosDBSqlContainerThroughput -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AccountName $accountName -DatabaseName $databaseName -Name $containerName | select throughput

Throughput
----------
         0
```

Full output:

```powershell
PS C:\windows\system32> $container = Get-AzCosmosDBSqlContainerthroughput `
        -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
        -AccountName $accountName -DatabaseName $databaseName `
        -Name $containerName

PS C:\windows\system32> $container 


Name                : ECvc
Id                  : /subscriptions/dxxxxx/resourceGroups/RG-01/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/xxxxx
                      01/sqlDatabases/xxxx/containers/cosmosscaleupordowntest/throughputSettings/default
Throughput          : 0
MinimumThroughput   : 
OfferReplacePending :
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/get-azcosmosdbsqlcontainerthroughput?view=azps-3.7.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's unclear what you are asking. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @stephenwade - what part is unclear? The OP wants to use PowerShell to retrieve the current throughput setting for a Cosmos DB container, via the Azure cmdlets, and is seeing an unexpected value being returned. Maybe the formatting could be improved (which I just took care of)?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is correct and I am unable to repro this cmdlet returning zero. This is also not a scenario with shared database throughput as this cmdlet is designed to throw an exception if throughput is not set on a resource. My only suggestion is to try the latest version of this module, [Az.CosmosDB 0.1.3](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.CosmosDB/0.1.3). We just updated it 5 days ago. It may have a bug fix.

If this issue persists for you, please file an issue on the [PowerShell Issues List](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues). This will get routed to the engineers working on these cmdlets.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't use (az) Powershell script but I'm able to read and update Cosmos DB RU using powershell.

```
$databasePrimaryKey = "************"
$cosmosDbAccountName = "************"
$databaseName = "************"
$primaryKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $databasePrimaryKey -AsPlainText –Force
```

Get the list of all container and configure RU (Collection name will not display)

```
Get-CosmosDbOffer -Context $cosmosDbContext
```

Update desire RU

```
Get-CosmosDbOffer -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id $collectionId |
    Set-CosmosDbOffer -Context $cosmosDbContext -OfferThroughput 400 -
```

OfferIsRUPerMinuteThroughputEnabled $true

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks Pankaj but i dont have cosmosdboffer cmdlet so i tried to install the latest which was failed, is that anything different to install it?

Comment: PS C:\windows\system32> Install-Module -Name CosmosDB
WARNING: Source Location 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/CosmosDB/3.7.0' is not valid.
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Package 'CosmosDB' failed to download.

Comment: use below command in a sequence 

1) Install-Module -Name AzureRM.profile
2) Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Resources
3) Install-Module -Name CosmosDB

Comment: AzureRM has been deprecated. You should not be advising people to use it.